# Two PS store accounts with same priviledges, but cannot buy game on one of them

Tags: ps4, psn

I'm trying to buy The Elder Scrolls 5 on my son's account which has no restrictions set. I can find the game in the PS store under my account, but not on his.

We have a PS4 with my account as primary and his as secondary. We do not have PS Plus, but I don't see why that would matter - with no restrictions we should both have access to all the games.

Answer (score 1):

Is your son's account was set up as sub-account (Family account)? Because if it's so, that's default setting (Perhaps, based on age).

You can change it so your son can see everything in the store, step by step:

1. Go to https://account.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/ , log in and click Account.
2. Click on Family Management on the left.
3. You'll see a list of family members that are tied to your account. Click on your son's account.
4. Click the Edit button next to Age Filtering for Online Content. Set it to Off (or whatever you prefer to) and click the Save button.

After that, your son's account should see everything (or contents based on setting).